# How do you delete the comma after the number?

Tags: c

So I have this exercise from my Coding class and we were tasked to input the user's input. However, we have to remove the comma of the last number of our output, and I'm struggling with how to remove that comma. Can anyone please help?

this is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_SIZE 100 

int main(){
    int arr[MAX_SIZE];
    int N, i;
    int * ptr = arr;    
    
    printf("Enter length: ");
    scanf("%d", &N);

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++){
        printf("Enter element %d: ", i+1);
        scanf("%d", ptr);
        ptr++;   
    }

    ptr = arr;

    printf("[");
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        printf("%d,", *ptr);

        ptr++;
    }

        printf("]");

    return 0;
}
```

for convenience, this is the output I got

```
Enter length: 5
Enter element 1: 1
Enter element 2: 2
Enter element 3: 3
Enter element 4: 4
Enter element 5: 5
[1,2,3,4,5,]
```

this is how the output should be

```
Enter length: 5
Enter element 1: 1
Enter element 2: 2
Enter element 3: 3
Enter element 4: 4
Enter element 5: 5
[1,2,3,4,5]
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You are addressing it from the wrong side. Don't "remove" the comma. If you have printed it, it is too late. Instead you should avoid printing it. Printing such a sequence contains of "print the first one" and "print any further elements", i.e. print first one without comma and then print following values with comma as long as you have more to print.

Comment: `printf("]");` --> `printf("\b]");`

Comment: @CGi03 this is a very poor solution.

Comment: Just one out of many possible solutions: https://ideone.com/ZQUxmm This solution avoids a conditional statement inside the loop.

Comment: OT: The use of `ptr` is not wrong but your code would be simpler to read by doing `printf("%d,", arr[i]);` and delete all code using `ptr`

Comment: And if the user types 246 as the number of values they want to enter into the array???

Comment: @Fe2O3 as the OP is obviously a beginner, they first need to learn how to walk, then we can think about running. For such simple tasks it is normally acceptable to assume the user behaves correctly.

Comment: @Gerhardh Give me a break. Many "newbie" questions are answered with quotes lifted from specifications using jargon that I have a hard time understanding... Newbies gotta learn, sometime, about "user data validation" and not simply "take it all on good faith"... It's not as easy as it was back in the day, but... My earlier comment may only serve to "raise awareness" if it is read and (hopefully) understood and remembered. "self reliance" 'cuz SO won't be available during the f2f interview sessions... No comment yet on "uninitialised N" and the user typing "forty-two"...

Comment: @SupportUkraine Corner: Applying suggested [solution](https://ideone.com/ZQUxmm) that avoids a conditional statement inside the loop here inadvertently prints a number when `N == 0`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica yes... and having the condition inside the loop will print `[]` when N is zero. Not sure what OP would want. Anyway, adding a `if (N > 0) { .... }` shouldn't be too difficult for OP to handle.

Answer (score 2):

Simple:

```
const char *sep = "";
printf( "[" );
for( i = 0; i < N; i++ ) {
    printf( "%s%d", sep, arr[ i ] );
    sep = ",";
}
printf( "]" );
```

Put the commas BEFORE the next value to be printed.
Specify the "prefix" to be "", until that is changed to ","

You'd be better off using "array indexing" throughout instead of shifting a pointer around the place... Too easy to forget to reset it to the beginning...

AND, add some code to check that `scanf` has assigned an integer value to the uninitialised variable 'N'! If the user types "four" in response to the first prompt, the value of N could be anything, even 243,478,658.... That's a LOT of data to be entering... In addition, the code should also check if the user types 120 to fill the 100 elements of the array.

EDIT: In this instance (surrounding brackets), we can even eliminate one line of code.

```
const char *sep = "[";
for( i = 0; i < N; i++ ) {
    printf( "%s%d", sep, arr[ i ] );
    sep = ",";
}
printf( "]" );
```

and then go on to please the "brace-o-phobes" by changing things around

```
i = 0;
for( char pre = '['; i < N; pre = ',' )
    printf( "%c%d", pre, arr[ i++ ] );
putchar( ']' );
```

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica at least I used curlies instead of a comma in this answer `:-)` Nice music...Z-z-z--z-z--z-z

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple *ternary* to control the format-string in `printf`, e.g.

```c
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        printf(i ? ",%d" : "%d", *ptr);

        ptr++;
    }
```

That only prints a comma **before** the number for numbers after the first. An equivalent long-form using `if-else` would be:

```c
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        if (i) {
            printf(",%d", *ptr);
        }
        else {
            printf("%d", *ptr);
        }
        
        ptr++;
    }
```

Also suggest the final `puts ("]");` to ensure your program is POSIX compliant -- outputting a final `'\n'` before program exit. Likewise, there is no need to call the variadic `printf()` function to output a single-character. A simple `putchar ('[');` will do.